# how to read docker image label on helm chart template

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm

My company it is using on their build process [sbt-native-packager](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html), which adds labels on docker images, those labels contains useful information (port number, service types, application name etc...).

I want to read those values and use them on Kubernetes Helm charts, is there any way to access those label values using [go templates](https://godoc.org/text/template) on helm charts?

Comment: is there a way to read those properties into separate environment variables during build time?

Comment: FYI these are not mustache, but go templates (https://godoc.org/text/template)

Comment: You're right, already edit for go template... Yes I can do it, however I would like to find a way (if possible) to render template without tooling dependencies (except helm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some steps you can do in order to get these variables to chart:

1. Extract desired labels in separate environment variables

   `PORT_NUMBER=$(command --to --extract --port)`
2. Set placeholders in your **values.yaml** file

**values.yaml**

```
image: 
  port: "$PORT_NUMBER"
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

3. Use [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) to replace values in values.yaml during build

Comment: That is something I want to avoid, but thanks for the step 3, I didn't know about `envsubst` 